# Creating and Setting ItemStacks in an Anvil Inventory (Bukkit/Spigot API)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How do I set an ItemStack in an anvil inventory? I need the method to be supported for versions 1.8.8-1.14.4. I can create the inventory, but can't set items. This is what I have:

```
void open(Player player) {
        Inventory createKitGUI = Bukkit.createInventory(null, InventoryType.ANVIL);

        createKitGUI.setItem(1, new ItemStack(XMaterial.PAPER.parseMaterial()));

        player.openInventory(createKitGUI);
    }
```

I've tried setting in slots 0 and 1 but it doesn't work. 0 and 1 are the first 2 slots in the anvil inventory.

Answer (score 3):

**WHY YOU CANNOT DO THIS WITHOUT NMS**

After further research I've found out this:

- You cannot cast CraftInventoryCustom to AnvilInventory because:

  1. AnvilInventory is a child class of CraftInventory.
  2. CraftInventoryCustom is a child class of CraftInventory.
  3. You cannot cast CraftInventoryCustom to AnvilInventory without casting to CraftInventory first.
  4. According to the main spigot developer on [this post](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/classcastexception-inventory-anvilinventory.199136/) he states that you cannot cast an CraftInventoryCustom to CraftInventory.

So your only chance is to implement an NMS solution.

**ANVIL GUI**

If you don't want to dive into NMS development then you can use the following API called [AnvilGUI](https://github.com/WesJD/AnvilGUI) by WesJD. Here you have the [documentation](https://docs.wesjd.net/AnvilGUI/) of this API.

Comment: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.inventory.CraftInventoryCustom cannot be cast to org.bukkit.inventory.AnvilInventory

Comment: See my latest edit. I'm afraid it cannot be done without handling packets.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but the thing is I tried using his API, but I always get this error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.wesjd.anvilgui.AnvilGUI$Builder
I even tried shading

Comment: What are you using to compile and export/pack? Gradle or Maven?

Comment: I'm using Maven

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml file, so that I can see where the problem is?